# Touchpad suddenly stopped working on boot

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

My touchpad stopped working one day randomly after powering up my laptop.  At first there was no cursor at all, but I ran some command that got it to appear (can't remember offhand what it was anymore) but I still couldn't move the cursor with the touchpad.  I am able to use an external mouse just fine.  None of the touchpad buttons respond or do anything.  I've tried editing

$ sudu vim /etc/default/grub
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to many different values like
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.reset quiet splash"` and running `sudo update-grub` and rebooting, but none have helped.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Since the bug I updated my kernal from 4.4 to 4.6 but it did not fix the problem.

```
$ uname -r
4.6.0-040600-generic
```

Here's my xinput with my external mouse plugged in.  Without it the only virtual core pointer will be Virtual core XTEST pointer.

```
 $ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Truevision HD                          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: You installed an unsupported kernel. Problems with unsupported kernels are off-topic at AskUbuntu.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is related to an unsupported kernel.

Comment: I can roll it back to 4.4 if that helps?  I'd really like some help with this

Comment: Maybe it won't help. Not all touchpads are supported. You can try 4.9 first.

Comment: Also it is possible that the touchpad is broken, or the cable is loose.

Comment: I updated to 4.9 and the problem persists.  I guess I will check the cables $ uname -a
Linux dan-PC 4.9.0-040900-generic #201612111631 SMP Sun Dec 11 21:33:00 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Also check the hardware button Fn+ something and bios settings.

Comment: I doubt Kernel version fixes anything here. Use `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` then boot with latest kernel `4.4.0-57` and ask your questions here whilst that is booted to get support from community. Also update your question with your hardware specs. Reply to this comment when you've done this and I'll vote to reopen your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was some hardware issue.  I didn't end up getting all the way to the touchpad, but I removed the hardrive and some other parts and put them back and it's working.  Maybe a wire was pinched or something.  My current xinput shows the Synaptics touchpad which wasn't showing up before.

```
$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```